# How to get group id in subtask instance while work with celery Group?

Tags: celery-task

When work with Celery 4.3.0 Chains,
Code like this:

```
class BaseTask(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        pass

@app.task(bind=True, base=BaseTask)
def add(self, x, y):
    return x+y

@app.task(bind=True, base=baseTask)
def add_1(self,x, y):
    return x+y

task = group(add.s(1,3), add_1.s(2,4))()
group_id = task.id
```

I can get group_id by taks.children[0]._cache.get("group"),

How can I get group_id in BaseTask on_success functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the id of the task’s group inside the [`app.task.Request`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#task-request) object, made available through the `Task` object, like so:

```python
class BaseTask(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        group_id = self.request.group
        # rest of your code
```